# displaying the td element only for the first element from the list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying the array elements inside the body tag and want to display a button only for the first element in the list. I am using the below code.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" >
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    <td>{{person.}}</td>
    <td ng-show='{in:$first}'>
      <button ng-click="skipActivity()" type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-warning pad-btn">Skip</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The skip button is visible for all the rows. I want to display the skip button only for the first row. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for $index
as

```
<td ng-show='0 == $index'>
  <button ng-click="skipActivity()" type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-warning pad-btn">Skip</button>
</td>
```

hope this may help you
**demo** http://dojo.telerik.com/OkALe

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the nature of the condition to display the button (it won't change unless the person array is changed) you can go a step forward and use **ng-if** instead of **ng-show**.